# Object in console shows getter with a value but in the code it returns undefined

Tags: javascript

The output in the console of the following code:

```
  console.log(userValues);
```

is:

[image: Getter called from console]

However, when I call it from the code (inside the `ngOnInit()`, I'm using Angular 6):

```
  console.log(userValues.USER_AUTH_MODE);
```

And this prints `undefined`.

Is there some other special way to call the getter that will return the object correctly?

Comment: you write MODE where the log says METHOD - it even has setter and getter logged for it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You circled "USER_AUTH_METHOD" property but are attempting to log "USER_AUTH_MODE" property which apparently does not exist